# How to call a javascript-delegate with parameters?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a javascript function call moveItem which takes two parameters source and destination.

I want to assign this function the the click-event of several buttons, each having different source and destinations.

OK, so without the parameter I would do something like this:

```
$('#myButton1').click(moveItem);

function moveItem() {
...
}
```

But what if moveItem looks like this:

```
function moveItem(source, destination) {
...
}
```

this doesn't seem to work:

```
$('#myButton1').click(moveItem('foo','bar'));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do quite what you want. You'll have to use an anonymous function to call `moveItem`:

```
$('#myButton1').click(function(){ moveItem('foo','bar'); };
```

When registering functions for events, the function signature has to match one of the supported signatures (because code in the click function is calling the handler). Since `moveItem` doesn't match, you have to wrap it in an anonymous function that does match.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do

```
$('#myButton1').click(function() {moveItem('foo','bar')});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myButton1').click(function(){moveItem(source, destination)});
```